# How to select only certain div elements in a list of div elements with selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have a list of divs as follows

[image]

From the list of divs given below, I only want to extract certain data from divs between `data-index=3` and `data-index=10`.

Currently I am able to extract all the divs using XPATH. But I don't want that. I want to only target specific divs.

How do I do that? Thank you

Comment: You could just loop `range(3,10)` and use the index to create the XPATH selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this XPath for **inclusive** 3 and 10:

```
//div[div[@data-index]]/div[@data-index[. &gt;= 3 and . &lt;= 10]]
```

Or this XPath for **exclusive** 3 and 10:

```
//div[div[@data-index]]/div[@data-index[. &gt; 3 and . &lt; 10]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use XPATH, you can loop through elements and filter attributes range that you expect to work with.

For example,

```py
def extract_data_by_index_range(elements, start_index, end_index, prop):

    extracted_data = []

    for element in elements:
        data_index = element.get_attribute('data-index')
        if data_index is not None:
            data_index = int(data_index)
            if start_index <= data_index <= end_index:
                extracted_data.append(element.get_property(prop))

    return extracted_data
```

You can change `get_property` to `get_attribute` by your needs or just get needed property directly.

You can try it there:

```py
url = "https://inputnum.w3spaces.com/saved-from-Tryit-2023-09-04.html"
driver.get(url)
divs = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[data-index]')
def extract_data_by_index_range(elements, start_index, end_index, prop):

    extracted_data = []

    for element in elements:
        data_index = element.get_attribute('data-index')
        if data_index is not None:
            data_index = int(data_index)
            if start_index <= data_index <= end_index:
                extracted_data.append(element.get_property(prop))

    return extracted_data

mapped_props = extract_data_by_index_range(divs, 3, 10, 'innerText')
```